# scrapy - condition on allowed_domains

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to know if it's possible, in python, to make a condition on a link like this : `if my_link is allowed:` 
I tried :

```
allowed_domains = ['exemple.com']

if mylink.exemple.com in allowed_domains:
    something
```

So my link is allowed but not written in allowed_domains... How could I do please?

Comment: Could you elaborate a specific example ? I don't really understand your thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at how `OffsiteMiddleware` is implemented ([link](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py)), specifically `should_follow` method. You might reuse the logic from there.